# Maximum parameter string limit passed in function PHP

Tags: php

I just wanna know that is there any limit of the parameter (string length) which passing in PHP function? How much of size of data can be passed in any function?

Comment: It all depends on the maximum amount of memory you have allocated to your php script `memory_limit`.  If you have a very large variable that you are passing to a function you could use pass by reference to cut down on your memory usage.

Comment: other than the usual memory_limit, php has no inherent limits that aren't due to the underlying platform. e.g. on a 32bit system, you can't have a string >=4gig-type of thing

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the PHP [documentation of strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)?

It says:

> **Note:** As of PHP 7.0.0, there are no particular restrictions regarding the length of a string on 64-bit builds. On 32-bit builds and in earlier versions, a string can be as large as up to 2GB (`2147483647` bytes maximum).

The actual maximum length of a string variable is determined by several factors:

- the amount of memory the PHP script is allowed to use (set by the [`memory_limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.resource-limits) setting in [`php.ini`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php));
- the amount of (physical and virtual) memory available on the computer;
- the amount of memory used by variables, objects and other data structures already created by the script;
- PHP version; version 7 implements a more efficient way to use the memory to store the data structures, allowing to store more data in the same amount of memory than PHP 5.